# iOS Get users iTunes mailing address? In app purchases for real products to ship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app where I want a user to touch "Buy Now". When that happens, Apple gets their 30% cut and then a physical item ships to the users mailing address.

- Is there any way of retrieving the users mailing address?
- Is there any problem in people buying real world consumables in the app?

So again, the use case is: A user sees an item they want to buy (ie. Toaster). They click "Buy Now" in the app.  An in app purchase occurs.  Once the purchase occurs our team receives the notification that we should ship an item. We somehow receive the user's mailing address (I suppose we can manually collect this before purchase). We then ship the item.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Reading through all these comments, how can I get a user to buy a real world good and have it shipped to them?

Comment: I don't think Apple lets you do this (unless they changed the app review terms again lately?).

Comment: I don't think you would ever be able to get the iTunes mailing account through legit means.

Comment: Would it not be better to have some form of website or external account system that doesn't depend on iTunes/In-App purchases? The user would log into that account within your application and use the information on that website for the purchases. Or do you want to use In-App purchases to make your app different? You could just ask the user for their e-mail address when they use your app to buy something, though.

Comment: There is no need to use the in-App purchase mechanics if you do ship physical goods.

Comment: Use of In-App purchases is not allowed for physical goods.  "Do not use In-App Purchase to sell real-world goods and services." from [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf)

Comment: Why don't you just have them submit payment information, process it, and ship them the goods?  Are you just trying to not deal with the payment verification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Use In-App Purchase to enable your users to purchase credits consumed within the app. **You cannot use In-App Purchase to offer physical goods and services used outside of your app.**

From [Apple's In-App Purchase Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe iTunes credit can only be used to buy virtual goods. You may want to double-check the App Store submission guidelines on this point. Also I believe that you cannot get any Personally Identifiable Information at all--certainly not the name and address of a user. You can prompt, but you should think about providing terms of use if you collect PII.